# WPF Rectangle moves in circles instead of spinning

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, mahapps.metro

I'm trying to animate a rectangle to spin instead of circle.  There is a video below to illustrate what I'm talking about.

https://www.screencast.com/t/M5rgy5gIicmB

Below is my code.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="-5 -5 -5 -5">
    <Label Content="RACKS"></Label>
    <Button x:Name="RefreshRacks" MaxHeight="20" MaxWidth="20" Margin="0" Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}" Click="RefreshRacks_Click" BorderBrush="Transparent">
        <Rectangle Width="15" Height="15" Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" >
            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill"
                                 Visual="{DynamicResource appbar_refresh}" />
            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <!-- giving the transform a name tells the framework not to freeze it -->
                <RotateTransform x:Name="noFreeze" />
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <Rectangle.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
        To="-360" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Rectangle.Triggers>
        </Rectangle>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: You need to set `CenterX and CenterY of your `RotateTransform` to be the center of the `Rectangle`, half of `Width` and `Height`. [Here's a sample](https://imgur.com/Sw0eAvm).

Comment: That worked!  Thanks

Answer (score -1):

CenterX and CenterY of your RotateTransform` to be the center of the Rectangle, half of Width and Height

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="-5 -5 -5 -5">
<Label Content="RACKS"></Label>
<Button x:Name="RefreshRacks" MaxHeight="20" MaxWidth="20" Margin="0" Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}" Click="RefreshRacks_Click" BorderBrush="Transparent">
    <Rectangle Width="15" Height="15" Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" >
        <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill"
                             Visual="{DynamicResource appbar_refresh}" />
        </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <!-- giving the transform a name tells the framework not to freeze it -->
            <RotateTransform x:Name="noFreeze" CenterX="7.5" CenterY="7.5"/>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <Rectangle.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
    To="-360" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Rectangle.Triggers>
    </Rectangle>
</Button>
```